# R - how to convert long-data dataframe to sparse matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, sparse-matrix, reshape

I have a large dataframe, 305k rows, with a two keys and a data column as follows:

[image]

I am trying to convert this to a sparse matrix using the following code in R:

```
#convert to factors
data$RID   = as.factor(data$RID)
data$HID   = as.factor(data$HID)
data$VALUE = as.numeric(data$VALUE)
str(data)

#remove nas
data = na.omit(data)

#create sparse matrix
X = with(data,sparseMatrix(i=RID, 
                           j=HID, 
                           x=VALUE,
                           dimnames=list(levels(RID), levels(HID))))
```

Which is producing the following error message:

```
Error in sparseMatrix(i = RID, j = HID, x = VALUE, dimnames = list(levels(RID),  : 
  NA's in (i,j) are not allowed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(i, !(m.i || i1)) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(j, !(m.j || i1)) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
```

I have removed NAs so i'm unsure why the error-NAs is appearing?
It also has reference to '+'s within the factors but i have checked all 36k factors and there are no '+'s there?

Does anyone know what the solution is?

I have included a snapshot of the first 20 rows of data below so you can re-produce the issue:

```
"RID" "HID" "VALUE"
"361838" "620631" 76.55
"361838" "620671" 82.61
"361838" "620787" 57.73
"361838" "621146" 58.65
"361838" "637825" 64.15
"361838" "637859" 82.79
"361838" "641254" 50.38
"361838" "642105" 72.88
"361838" "646469" 45.79
"361838" "648400" 82.06
"395855" "301340" -5.12
"395855" "649304" 41.88
"395855" "650324" -30.83
"395855" "657458" 46.47
"395855" "658028" -0.53
"395855" "659504" 28.84
"395855" "660506" 29.03
"395855" "660519" 14.16
"395855" "660521" -38.17
"395855" "660547" 35.45
```

Although when i look at the factors, i get the following:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ RID  : Factor w/ 30608 levels "361838","395855",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ HID  : Factor w/ 37399 levels "2018","7990",..: 11604 11624 11709 11740 14031 14049 15086 15457 16821 17270 ...
 $ VALUE: num  76.5 82.6 57.7 58.6 64.2 ...
```

Comment: Can you show us what `str(data)` and `str(X)` report? If you provide a sample of your data e.g. `dput(head(data, 20))` so that we can reproduce your problem, it would be helpful. One possibility is that `RID` and `HID` are not factors.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the additional information, rather than post them in comments. If you've updated your data by converting your columns to factors, please edit your question as well to reflect the new errors you are getting. It'll also be useful to show how you are removing the NAs.

Comment: I have now converted RID and HID to factors and removed any NAs as per the first suggestion. I have re-edited the question to show the current issue and error

Answer (score 2):

Try converting `RID` and `HID` to numeric in your call to `sparseMatrix`:

```
X <- with(data, sparseMatrix(i=as.numeric(RID), 
                       j=as.numeric(HID), 
                       x=as.numeric(VALUE),
                       dimnames=list(levels(RID), levels(HID))))
```

The reason why `RID` and `HID` need to be converted into factors first, then into numeric in the call to `sparseMatrix` is that otherwise `sparseMatrix` will take the values of `RID` and `HID` as indices for the rows/columns. In other words,

```
test <- data.frame(x = 101:105, y = 201:205, v = 1:25)
dim(with(test, sparseMatrix(i = x, j = y, x = v)))
# [1] 105 205
```

gives you a 105 x 205 matrix, even though what we had in mind, treating `x` and `y` as keys, was just a 5 x 5 matrix.